# Android Firebase, Get position of key in node

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ranking

I want to get data according to user's ranking. First order by user's points and get users position in node. But I can't think of the way to implement this.

First This is my firebase 'users' node
[image]

Maybe It will be like 'databaseRef.child("users").orderByChild("points")...'
I don't know from here.

ps. It's not get nth item. It's 'where is the item' ( item's nth )

Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to retrieve?

Comment: @PeterHaddad 
I want to get the user rankings  by points. I'm sorry I did not explain well in English.

Comment: okay and what is the problem.. the query that you wrote is correct.

Comment: @PeterHaddad Oh...Can I get users position with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by adding a ctr in you dataSnapshot loop

```
myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
final Query query = myRef.orderByChild("points");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        int total = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        int i = 0;
        // loop through dataSnapshot
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String nickName = childSnapshot.child("nickName").getValue(String.class);
            if (nickName.equals(mUser.getNickName()) {
                //when nickName would match
                int userPlace = total - i;
                int points = childSnapshot.child("points").getValue(Interger.class);

                //do something here
                break;
            } else {
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: You genius! Thank you for real.

Comment: @Junburg true that the result would be ascending. So you could do `int total = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()` then `userPlace = total - i;`

Answer (score 2):

Kindly read

- [**`Retrieving Data`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).
- [**`How Data is Ordered`**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-ordered-data)

> The callback function receives a DataSnapshot, which is a snapshot of
>   the data. A snapshot is a picture of the data at a particular database
>   reference at a single point in time. Calling val() / getValue() on a
>   snapshot returns the a language-specific object representation of the
>   data. If no data exists at the reference's location, the snapshot's
>   value is null.

If you want to get all **`points`** then check this **LOGIC**.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("products");
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(
            new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    ArrayList<Integer> points = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : products.entrySet()){
                        Map singleUser = (Map) entry.getValue();
                        points.add((Integer) singleUser.get("points"));
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    //handle databaseError
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

I solve this problem. Android_K.Doe's answer is right. I add some code in his code. Because Firebase database does not give descending query.

```
final Query query = databaseReference.child("users").orderByChild("points");
        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                int i = 0;
                int all = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                Log.d(TAG, "all: " + all);
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    String nickName = ds.child("nickName").getValue(String.class);
                    if (nickName.equals(user.getNickName())) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "nickName: " + user.getNickName());
                        int userPlace = i;
                        Log.d(TAG, "position: " + userPlace);
                        myInfoRankingNumTxt.setText(Integer.toString(all - (i)) + "위");
                        break;
                    } else {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: I missed the ascending. Good thing it help though